# Diagonalization versus s.d. product for non-commuting Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Although the application of the following is in quantum physics, the question per se is mathematical:

I have seen two characterizations of the problem in measuring a discrete variable of a state $\psi$ exactly with each of two non-commuting Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$:

1. The product of the standard deviations ( $=\sqrt{\langle \psi | A^2 | \psi \rangle - \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle^2}$ and ditto for $B$) $\geq 1$.
2. One cannot simultaneously diagonalize the matrix representations of $A$ and $B$
   (i.e., if $A = U^\dagger CU$ and $B = V^\dagger DV$, for unitary $U$ and $V$ and diagonal $C$ and $D$, with $\dagger$ denoting the adjoint), then $U \neq V$.

Where is the link between these two?

Answer (score -1):

In quantum mechanics, the mean of an observable $A$ in the state $\psi$ is given by

$$\langle A \rangle_\psi = \langle \psi |A|\psi \rangle,$$

and from this the variance of $A$ in $\psi$ is usually defined by

$$\langle(\Delta A)^2 \rangle_\psi := \langle (A-\langle A \rangle_\psi)^2 \rangle_\psi = \| (A - \langle A \rangle_\psi) \psi \|^2 = \langle A^2 \rangle_\psi - \langle A \rangle_\psi^2.$$

The standard deviation is then given by taking the square root.

> **Theorem:** (Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle)
>
> $$\langle (\Delta A)^2 \rangle_\psi \langle (\Delta B)^2 \rangle_\psi \geq \frac{1}{4} | \langle [A,B] \rangle_\psi |^2$$

*Proof:* Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we obtain
$$| \langle \psi | [A,B] \psi \rangle | = | \langle A \psi| B \psi \rangle - \langle B \psi| A \psi \rangle| \leq 2 \| A \psi \| \| B \psi \|.$$

Square and substitute $A \to A - \langle A \rangle_\psi$, $B \to B- \langle B \rangle_\psi$ to finish the proof. **Q.E.D.**

You can observe directly that the product of the standard deviations has lower bound $>0$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are non-commuting operators. This is statement (1).

From linear algebra, you might remember the following

> **Theorem:** (without proof) A set of diagonalisable matrices commutes if and only if the set is simultaneously diagonalisable.

You can find the proof for that theorem in most linear algebra textbooks, in case you are interested.

Putting these two theorems together, you can see the connection between statement (1) and statement (2), assuming you have two non-commuting operators $A$ and $B$. I am however a bit confused because you claim the lower bound to be $1$, which is not the case in general.

For example, taking $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with the two operators

$$x_k: \psi(x) \mapsto x_k \psi(x), \; p_k: \psi(x) \mapsto \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_k}$$

which are the components of position and momentum, you can compute

$$i [p_k,x_\ell] = \hbar \delta_{k \ell}$$

and thus

$$\langle (\Delta p_k)^2 \rangle \langle ( \Delta x_\ell )^2 \rangle \geq \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \delta_{k \ell}.$$

Comment: First, you are right that I mistakenly put "1" (thinking in terms of units of h-bar/2) for a special case instead of writing |<s|[A,B]|s>|/2. This mistake aside, when I put together the two theorems, the only obvious link I see is that both deal with non-commuting operators. But I just noticed in the Wiki article on uncertainty there is a more direct connection: that there is a fourier transform between the two bases, and a non-zero function and its fourier transform cannot both be sharply localized. I still have to delve into wave harmonics to better understand this, however.

Comment: @nomadreid: Which bases do you mean? My point was that both statement (1) and (2) are equivalent to $[A,B] \neq 0$, in case it wasn't clear. I thought you were trying to understand how one comes up with these two results.

Comment: First, which bases I meant:  A is a linear map in the Hilbert space, and the basis  with respect to which A is represented by a diagonal matrix is the basis I had in mind for A. Then, in the same way, a basis for B. Secondly, both (1) and (2) are consequences of |[A,B]|>0, but are they equivalent? Thirdly, apparently I did not make myself clear: when I wrote "what is the link?" I meant what the link is between the two results; I already have the derivations of each result. (I mean something more direct than both being consequences of non-commuting.)

Comment: @nomadreid: Yes, they are equivalent, which is what I have shown in my post. First, I have shown that $[A, B] \neq 0$ is equivalent to (1) and then, I have given you the theorem that it is also equivalent to (2). Because equivalence of statements is an equivalence relation, (1) and (2) are equivalent to each other. This also applies to your third point: The point of my post was to show that (1) and (2) are not just consequences of $A$ and $B$ being non-commutative, but all three statements are equivalent!

Comment: Ah, yes, as you point out in the statement of the theorem, the non-commutativity is equivalent to the non-diagonalizability. But in the proof for HUP (I have the proof that you sketched in a somewhat more complete form), there is a step in which one drops a non-negative term to get the inequality (I have , so I have not checked whether one can work the proof backwards to make the direction of HUP to non-commutativity. It would seem reasonable, but the devil is in the details.